# Analog STDP switch using tactile button with state control

Tags: switches, integrated-circuit

I'm trying to implement a circuit that consist of 16 similar modules. Each module is a processed signal line which has to be routed into one of two outputs. Shure the SPDT is simple and rugged solution but I'd like to use tactile switch to choose which output the signal goes. And the switch has to remember its state after the circuit is off the power. Is there any way to implement this using DIP or SIP ICs? Thanks!
Please, don't blame me hard form my bad English )))

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want a 16PDT (electronic) switch. Look up analog multiplexers, that's how they're usually implemented. Here's for example the functional diagram from [the datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MC14551B-D.PDF) of a 4PDT one:

[image]

You'll need use four of these.

You also need some additional memory circuitry to remember the state without power, like NOR flash, e.g. found in a microcontroler, if you want to completely avoid a mechanical way of remembering the settings.

And you can still find DIP packages for both analog multiplexers (e.g. [BU4551](http://rohmfs.rohm.com/en/products/databook/datasheet/ic/logic_switch/standard_logic/bu4551bc-e.pdf) is the same type as the one above) and microcontrollers (e.g. ATMega328P aka arduino, or a smaller one like [PIC12F617](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/41388A.pdf)). You can find multiplexers with more (than four) channels on a chip, but usually not in DIP because they get large.